# SQLite return wrong text

Tags: java, android, sqlite

SQLite return wrong alarm description in list from method **getAllAlarmInfo**

But correct **Alarm.class** in method **addAlarm_info**

Alarm is added in activity

```
SQL db=new SQL(getBaseContext());
db.addAlarm_info(newAlarm);
```

Alarm initialize in other code.

Сan there be a problem in method **addAlarm_info** ?

**SQL.class**

```
public class SQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
   
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AlarmInfoDB";

    public SQL(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create book table
        String CREATE_ALARM_INFO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE alarm_info ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "ALARM_TIME TEXT, "+
                "ALARM_DAYS_CODE TEXT, "+
                "ALARM_WORK_ON INTEGER, "+
                "ALARM_VIBRATION_ON INTEGER, "+
                "ALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK INTEGER, "+
                "ALARM_DESCRIPTION TEXT)";
        // create books table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ALARM_INFO_TABLE);
    }
  
    // Books table name
    private static final String TABLE_ALARM_INFO = "alarm_info";
    // Books Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM_TIME = "ALARM_TIME";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM_DAYS_CODE = "ALARM_DAYS_CODE";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM_WORK_ON = "ALARM_WORK_ON";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM_VIBRATION_ON = "ALARM_VIBRATION_ON";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK = "ALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION = "ALARM_DESCRIPTION";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_ALARM_TIME,KEY_ALARM_DAYS_CODE,KEY_ALARM_WORK_ON,KEY_ALARM_VIBRATION_ON,KEY_ALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK,KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION};
    
   public void addAlarm_info(Alarm alarm){
        Log.d("addAlarm_info", alarm.toString());
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ALARM_TIME, alarm.getALARM_TIME()); // get
        values.put(KEY_ALARM_DAYS_CODE, alarm.getALARM_DAYS_CODE()); // get
        values.put(KEY_ALARM_WORK_ON, alarm.isALARM_WORK_ON()); // get
        values.put(KEY_ALARM_VIBRATION_ON, alarm.isALARM_VIBRATION_ON()); // get
        values.put(KEY_ALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK, alarm.isALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK()); // get
        values.put(KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION, alarm.getALARM_DESCRIPTION()); // get
        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_ALARM_INFO, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

        System.out.println(" addAlarm_info values: "+values);
        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }

    // **Get All**
    public List<Alarm> getAllAlarmInfo() {
        List<Alarm> alarms = new LinkedList<>();
        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALARM_INFO;
        //2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Alarm alarm;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                alarm = new Alarm();
                alarm.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                alarm.setALARM_TIME(cursor.getString(1));
                alarm.setALARM_DAYS_CODE(cursor.getString(2));
                alarm.setALARM_WORK_ON(cursor.getInt(3));
                alarm.setALARM_VIBRATION_ON(cursor.getInt(4));
                alarm.setALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK(cursor.getInt(5));
                alarm.setALARM_DESCRIPTION(cursor.getString(6));
                // Add book to books
                alarms.add(alarm);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d("getAllBooks()", alarms.toString());
        // return books
        return alarms;
    }
//**Other code**//   
}
```

**Log.d**

```
D/addAlarm_info:  id:-0- / time:11:41 / days:null / description: test
I/System.out:  addAlarm_info values: ALARM_WORK_ON=1 ALARM_DELETE_AFTER_WORK=0 ALARM_TIME=11:41 ALARM_DAYS_CODE=0000000 ALARM_VIBRATION_ON=0 ALARM_DESCRIPTION=test
D/getAllBooks(): [id:-210- / time:11:41 / days:Один раз / description: 0]
```

if problem in **addAlarm** why it correct add other fields.
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Please avoid `SELECT *` queries, specify the columns you want.

Comment: it may occur because you've not handle database changes in onUpgrade's method, so uninstall app from emulator and run again may work correct.

Comment: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database add this library to view your sqlite database while  working on it.  It may help you in debugging your problem.

Comment: also cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION )); try this to get data. instead of alarm.setALARM_DESCRIPTION(cursor.getString(6));

Comment: @kelvin **cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION ))** it works , thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are passing wrong Column index. Please use

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION ));
```

to get data of a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

change `alarm.setALARM_DESCRIPTION(cursor.getString(6));`

to `alarm.setALARM_DESCRIPTION(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM_DESCRIPTION )));`